# How to accept many requests from client

Tags: java, tomcat

I am developing a struts2 project in Tomcat server.

I try to post 6000 request from client to my server API. but my server API only accept about more than 2000 requests. 4000 other are failed.

i got message from client like below:

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

my server.xml have config:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="1000000" maxThreads="50000"  keepAliveTimeout="3200000"     minSpareThreads="10000" acceptCount="13000" maxIdleTime="1000000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Does any one have a solution to allow my server API can get all client requests?

Please help me!
Thanks

Comment: What version of tomcat do you use? Do you have the tcnative dll's in your PATH?

Comment: Do you try to connect 6000 times at once (i.e. do you try to create 6000 connections at the same time) or 6000 times one connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this causes your problem, but your configuration values seems to be far too high!

- maxThreads=50000 means more than 15 GB memory (win32) when all threads are used!
- minSpareThreads=10000 means about 3 GB memory consumption on startup (win32)!
- keepAliveTimeout=3200000 means a connection stays open for >53 hours if not used/closed by the client!
- maxIdleTime=1000000 means unused threads continue to exist for up to 16 hours before they are destroyed!

Comment: Since Tomcat7, you also have acceptCount. This accepts connections, but waits for threads to become available. So you could reduce the threads further to e.g. 100, while still accepting 6000 connections.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to some error on the server which you can see when you look into the server's error log.

One simple reason could be the database: If you create one database transaction per thread, then you need to configure the connection pool (and probably the database itself) to allow 6000 concurrent transactions.